# generating random php link with if else prefix

Tags: php

i am generating random links using array but unable to add some value as per array random selection.
this file is language file which has values for different language

```
if($c2[2]=='en' || $c2[3]=='en'){$htmllang='en';$alt='Download';$text1='Wallpapers';$text2='HOLLYWOOD';}
elseif($c2[2]=='af' || $c2[3]=='af'){$htmllang='af';$alt='Aflaai';$text1='Wallpapers';$text2='HOLLYWOOD';}
else($c2[2]=='am' || $c2[3]=='am'){$htmllang='am';$alt='አውርድ';$text1='የግድግዳ';$text2='የሆሊዉድ';}
else($c2[2]=='ar' || $c2[3]=='ar'){$htmllang='ar';$alt='تحميل';$text1='خلفيات';$text2='هوليوود';}
```

here is code which is generating random links

```
$extpo = array("af","sq","am","ar");
$random_keys=array_rand($extpo,3);

shuffle($extpo);
$randlink='<a href="http://somesitesss.com/some/'.$extpo[0].'/'.$city2.'">'.$extpo[0].'</a>';

  $city2 is number .No issue here
```

it generates link like this

```
 http://somesitesss.com/some/am/566556
```

i want it to include $alt values before no. like this

[http://somesitesss.com/some/am/አውርድ/566556](http://somesitesss.com/some/am/%E1%8A%A0%E1%8B%8D%E1%88%AD%E1%8B%B5/566556)

any help will be great

Comment: So, what's the problem with concatenating your value in a `$randlink`?

Comment: @u_mulder its randomly generating how to pass those variables and concatenate ?

Comment: I don't understand. Why not `$randlink = $randlink . '/' . $alt`?

Comment: @u_mulder which $alt value it will take  ?? there are severals

Comment: It will take the value which is created in the proper case of your `if`.

Comment: How does first block of `if`s is connected with random link generation?

Comment: @u_mulder u r right. but i want alt value as per array random otherwise you can see that it will add english value in chines or vice versa

Comment: @u_mulder that language file is external file and its not connected to random link generation but i want to connect as its included in top so i think i should pass one more loop after shuffle and select that alt based on shuffle value

Comment: @u_mulder actually this is not the case. u have created straight forward so in this case there is no issue but situation is based on $c2[2] value real page is being rendered and after that we are trying to show some other language links. i have not seen clearly ur answer  .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear what you want so I maybe wrong)
Here's the code I think it should be:

```
$extpo = array("af","sq","am","ar");
// I don't think that you need $random_keys if you `shuffle` array
//$random_keys = array_rand($extpo,3);

shuffle($extpo);
$lang_key = $extpo[0];
// Okey, now `$lang_key` holds your lang code:
// Now I use your block of `if`s but I compare `$lang_key`
// As I don't know what is `$c2`

if ($lang_key == 'en'){
    $htmllang='en';$alt='Download';$text1='Wallpapers';$text2='HOLLYWOOD';
} elseif ($lang_key == 'af') {
    $htmllang='af';$alt='Aflaai';$text1='Wallpapers';$text2='HOLLYWOOD';
} elseif ($lang_key == 'am') {
    $htmllang='am';$alt='አውርድ';$text1='የግድግዳ';$text2='የሆሊዉድ';
} elseif ($lang_key =='ar') {
    $htmllang='ar';$alt='تحميل';$text1='خلفيات';$text2='هوليوود';
}
// now your `$alt` has a proper value according to `$lang_key`
// get a link:
$randlink='<a href="http://somesitesss.com/some/' . $lang_key . '/' . $alt . '/' . $city2 . '">'.$lang_key.'</a>';
```

Comment: not really. above code is straight forward if else but real situation is that random link is just extra in other language but all content are being displayed as per $c2[2] language so above solution will not work as all other data will be in that language in this case and above answer is straight line but question is not